# CSS Rotate Text Vertical - Extra Space on both sides

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-animations

When I rotate and inline layer with TEXT, it adds extra space (width of large text) on the rotation, I dont want to fix. What is the best way to avoid extra space (width of element) on both sides when rotating with CSS.

Below is my Code:

```css
.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.rotate:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  margin-top: 100%;
}

.rotate:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;" class="rotate">
  <span style="displock;width:100%;font-size: 55px;color: #222222;opacity: 0.15;white-space: nowrap;">BACKGROUND</span>
  <span style="display:block;width:100%;font-size: 45px;color: #222222;text-align:center;">TITLE</span>

</div>
Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try to use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) .

> The `writing-mode` CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rGJGzQ?editors=1100

```css
.rotate {
  writing-mode:vertical-rl;
  transform:scale(-1);
  width:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}

body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end; 
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;" class="rotate">
  <span style="displock;width:100%;font-size: 55px;color: #222222;opacity: 0.15;white-space: nowrap;">BACKGROUND</span>
  <span style="display:block;width:100%;font-size: 45px;color: #222222;text-align:center;">TITLE</span>

</div>
Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element
```

---

or `transform:rotate(-90deg)` *(which was your first choice)*, but with a pseudo to reset height according to text-length. (this requires to use rgba() colors and set both line of text in a single container. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RLQLJG?editors=1100

```css
.rotate {
  width:110px;
}
.rotate>span   {
  display:inline-block; 
  transform:rotate(-90deg)
}
.rotate > span:before {
  content:'';
  padding-top:100%;
  float:left;
}

body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

```html
   <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;" class="rotate">
    <span style=" font-size: 55px;color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);white-space: nowrap;">BACKGROUND<br/>
    <span style="display:block;font-size: 45px;color: #222222;text-align:center;">TITLE</span></span>    
   </div>
      Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element Some randome text here should be close to the rotated element
```

**Both technics** here, **requires** to set a width to the rotating text container and are build from a flex container. It should work in IE,FF,Chrome.  *(`display:table/table-cell` can be another **display** option for older browser)*

Comment: Thanks - but doesnt seem to work in IE11, secondly if I give margin e.g. margin-top:10px; I have to change it margin-left:10px...

Comment: @Themer would this old example work for you ?  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zqVgMM `-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  /* old Win safari */
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  /* writing-mode:sideways-lr;should be the one */  
  /* eventually untill sideways-lr is working everywhere */
  transform: scale(-1, -1);`

Answer (score 10):

`transforms` are **entirely** visual...they do NOT affect the layout of elements. Space is not being *added*...it's there all the time.

Consider using `writing-mode` instead.

```css
.rotate {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-align: center;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  background: pink;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <h2>BACKGROUND</h2>
  <h1 >TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

> The writing-mode CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.
>
> <sup>[Writing-mode @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer

```
<div class="fixed-left">
  <div class="fixed-left-inner">
    <div class="fixed-left-item">
      <div class="fixed-left-text">Text might be on left side</div>
      <div class="fixed-left-text">Text might be on left side</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



.fixed-left{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .fixed-left-inner{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .fixed-left-item{
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0,50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 110px;
    width: 220px;
 }
 .fixed-left-text{
      font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/13205/

`vertical-align` is the key to answer.

Comment: you forced the width of the container and we still have spaces on the rotated elements